# How to get only Twitter follower count with JavaScript using Twitter API V1.1?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, svg, twitter

I want to use JavaScript/jQuery to get my Twitter follower count in `script.js` file and pass the value to `index.html` file to display the value on the html web page. I will not be hosting the web files on the internet.

I  have been searching for weeks to get Twitter follower counts  but the solutions I found are either outdated (due to Twitter API v1 being retired), does not work, or involving languages that I have no experience with such as PHP. I have tried `cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json` which is the most popular solution but I always faced problems from CORS and Twitter developers do not recommend it.

I thought that by using https://shields.io/ which generates an SVG, I can extract my follower count by accessing the XML data. However, I have absolutely no idea how to do that. For my account it’s https://img.shields.io/twitter/follow/ritorudemon69.svg?style=social.

Any solutions are appreciated as long as it works.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps and create an API token.
2. Make request using, [users/show](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) API endpoint.

A sample cURL,

```sh
curl --request GET 
    --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterdev' 
    --header 'authorization: Bearer <API_TOKEN>'
```

Sample Fetch,

```js
fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterdev", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <API_TOKEN>"
  }
})
```

Comment: I have managed to create a Twitter developer account and obtained an API token. However, I do not know how to include a curl into JavaScript

Comment: I've updated the answer with a fetch request. cURL is a tool to make HTTP requests in the command line. You cannot use it in Javascript.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the heads up